# Can I use ReLU in autoencoder as activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders

When implementing an autoencoder with neural network, most people will use sigmoid as the activation function.

Can we use ReLU instead? (Since ReLU has no limit on the upper bound, basically meaning the input image can have pixel bigger than 1, unlike the restricted criteria for autoencoder when sigmoid is used).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's a discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pylearn-dev/iWqctW9nkAg) (from July 2013) indicating that there might be some issues with it, but it can be done.

Çağlar Gülçehre (from Yoshua Bengio's lab) said he successfully used the following technique in [Knowledge Matters: Importance of Prior Information for Optimization](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4083):

> train the first DAE as usual, but with rectifiers in the hidden layer:
>   
>       `a1(x) = W1 x + b1
>       h1 = f1(x) = rectifier(a1(x)) 
>       g1(h1) = {sigmoid}(V1 h1 + c1)`
>   
>   minimize cross-entropy or MSE loss, comparing g1(f1(corrupt(x))) and x. the sigmoid is optional depending on the data.
>
> train the 2nd DAE with noise added before the f1 rectifier and use softplus reconstruction units with MSE loss:
>   
>        `h2 = f2(h1) = rectifier(W2 h1 + b2)
>        g2(h2) = softplus(V2 h2 + c2)`
>   
>   minimize $\lVert f_1(x) - g_2(f_2(\mathrm{rectifier}(\mathrm{corrupt}(a_1(x))))) \rVert^2 + \lambda_1 \lVert W \rVert_1 + \lambda_2 \lVert W \rVert_2$

Xavier Glorot, also from the Bengio lab, said he did the same except for replacing $\lVert W \rVert_1$ with an $L_1$ penalty "on the activation values" (presumably $\lVert g_2(\dots) \rVert_1$?) in both [Domain Adaptation for Large-Scale Sentiment Classification: A Deep Learning Approach](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/ICML2011Glorot_342.pdf) (ICML 2011) and in [Deep sparse rectifier neural networks](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/AISTATS2011_GlorotBB11.pdf) (AISTATS 2011).

Comment: Thanks for quick response! So you are saying there is some issue in optimizing the auteencoder when ReLU is used instead of Sigmoid?

Comment: It seems like it can cause issues, yes, but it can definitely be done if you set up the learning process correctly. It might help to read the linked papers.

Comment: I am experimenting with a simple autoencoder on the MNIST dataset. I use fully connected networks with 784-128-64-2-64-128-784 architecture. I use relus everywhere, but am experimenting with the bottleneck layer (relu or linear) and the output layer (relu or sigmoid). Using rectifier in the output leads to worse performance; sigmoid does better. For sigmoid output, linear bottleneck seems to be doing slightly better. So my favourite combination for these two layers is linear/sigmoid. (By the way, using sigmoids on *all* layers makes it clearly worse.)

Comment: @ameoba It's not surprising to me that relu outputs are bad: if you know the outputs have certain bounds, it makes sense to use an activation function that constrains you to those bounds. I'm not super experienced in this area, but I'd probably try out an [ELU](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07289) or a leaky ReLU for the hidden layers.

Comment: @Dougai, I think it is because ReLU has 0 everywhere when x<=0, and therefore make the output always positive, which may limitt he possibility of reconstruction. I agree that we can use something that has non-zero when x<0, such as ELU or pReLU, etc to improve the reconstruction.

Comment: Oh, wow, I was not aware of ELUs! Thanks a lot for the tip, Dougal. I tried them, and they do work better. Deep learning is amazing: new tricks appear every year and nobody has any idea why some work better than others. (CC to @RockTheStar). By the way, I also find that Adam optimizer performs pretty awesome.

Comment: @amoeba exactly, Adam is better than adadetla or adagrad for learning learning rate dynamically.